# Firefox treating new iframe src as popup from jquery .click() trigger

Tags: jquery, firefox, popup, click, submit

I have two forms, and I am trying to submit them both at the same time. One is posting to our PHP framework, and the other is posting to an external system (a prestashop install) which seems to require that the user "visit" the page through a normal click submit of the form to process the form.

My solution is, fire one form after firing the other

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $('#loginForm2').hide(1);
    $("#loginButton").click(function() {
        $("#userEmail2").val($("#userEmail").val());
        $("#userPassword2").val($("#userPassword").val());
        $.post(
            $("#loginForm").attr("action"), $("#loginForm").serialize(), function(data) {
                // alert('posted to users/login successfully');
                $("#SubmitLogin").click();
            }
        );
        return false;
    });
    function refresh() {
        location.reload();
    }
});
```

The #loginForm2 form is being sent to a hidden iframe on that same page, and that iframe refreshes after it has loaded the page (and logged in the user).

```
<iframe id="loginIframe" style="display:none;" onload="refresh();"></iframe>
```

This works great in Chrome and Safari, but in Firefox, it treats the iframe as a popup and won't do it (unless the user says allow popup).

Is there any way to get around Firefox thinking this iframe is a popup? I understand why it's doing it; it's not a real event that the user clicked, it's a fake mouseclick from jquery. I've looked up some solutions to try and fire an "authentic" mouseclick but haven't found anything that seems to work.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here's the solution:

Make it so that you're clicking the external system (prestashop) form's submit button instead of the primary system's login button (use CSS to hide the primary one and to show the external one). Then do it like this:

```
    $("#SubmitLogin").click(function() {
        var loaded = 0;
        $("#userEmail2").val($("#userEmail").val());
        $("#userPassword2").val($("#userPassword").val());
        $.post(
            $("#loginForm").attr("action"), $("#loginForm").serialize(), function(data) {
                loaded++;
                if (loaded > 1) {
                    location.reload();
                }
            }
        );
        $('#loginIframe').load(function() {
            loaded++;
            if (loaded > 1) {
                location.reload();
            }
        });
    });
```

The loaded variable is to ensure that if the prestashop window loads before the primary login's serialized data is sent, it doesn't refresh without finishing the primary login.

And obviously, the iframe looks like this

```
<iframe id="loginIframe" name="loginIframe" style="display:none;"></iframe>
```

Tested in Chrome Firefox and Safari.